# strict standards error with variables

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting the following error message on certain pages of a WordPress site I'm working on:

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/xf_integration/include/xf_replacement_comment_handler.php on line 287

What would cause this to display?

This is the code on line 287:

```
if($threadModel->canReplyToThread($thread, $forum, $errorKey = ''))
```

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure, but it might be `$errorKey = ''`

Comment: ^^ your mixing function definition syntax, with function execution syntax

Comment: @mloureiro Thank you!